# How to create only 1 class instance when using Gunicorn and multiple workers?

Tags: python, websocket, gunicorn, falconframework

I have a simple Python backend using `falcon` and `websockets`. If a client makes a call to an endpoint (e.g., to submit data) all other connected clients are notified via their respective websocket connection, i.e., the backend makes a broadcast to all currently connected clients. In general, this works just fine. Here's the minimal script for the `falcon` app

```
import falcon

from db.dbmanager import DBManager
from ws.wsserver import WebSocketServer
from api.resources.liveqa import DemoResource

dbm = DBManager() # PostgreSQL connection pool; works fine with multiple workers

wss = WebSocketServer() # Works only with 1 worker

app = falcon.App()

demo_resource = DemoResource(dbm, wss)

app.add_route('/api/v1/demo', demo_resource)
```

And here is the code for the `websockets` server which I instantiate and pass the resource class:

```
import json
import asyncio
import websockets
import threading


class WebSocketServer:

    def __init__(self):
        self.clients = {}
        self.start_server()


    async def handler(self, ws, path):
        session_id = path.split('/')[-1]

        if session_id in self.clients:
            self.clients[session_id].add(ws)
        else:
            self.clients[session_id] = {ws}

        try:
            async for msg in ws:
                pass # The clients are not supposed to send anything
        except websockets.ConnectionClosedError:
            pass
        finally:
            self.clients[session_id].remove(ws)


    async def send(self, client, msg):
        await client.send(msg)


    def broadcast(self, session_id, msg):

        if session_id not in self.clients:
            return

        for client in self.clients[session_id]:
            try:
                asyncio.run(self.send(client, json.dumps(msg)))
            except:
                pass


    def start_server(self):
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        start_server = websockets.serve(self.handler, host='111.111.111.111', port=5555)
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
        threading.Thread(target=asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever).start()
```

I use Gunicorn as server for the backend, and it works if I use just 1 worker. However, if I try `--workers 2` I get the error that port `5555` is already in use. I guess this makes sense as each worker is trying to create a `WebSocketServer` instance using the same ip/port-pair.

What is the best / cleanest / most phytonic way to address this? I assume that I have to ensure that only one `WebSocketServer` instance is created. But how?

On a side note, I assume that a `DBManager` instance get created for each worker as well. While it doesn't throw an error as there can be multiple connections pools, I guess ensuring a single instance of `DBManager` is also the preferred way.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, even running with one worker is potentially problematic, because Gunicorn is primarily a [pre-forking server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25834333/what-exactly-is-a-pre-fork-web-server-model), and forking a process with threads is, in general, unsafe and may lead to unpredictable results.

One way to solve this is to use Gunicorn's [server hooks](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#server-hooks) to only start a thread (in this case a WebSocket server) in one of the workers, and only do that after forking. For instance,

```py
import logging
import os
import threading

import falcon
import gunicorn.app.base

logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)


class HelloWorld:
    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        resp.media = {'message': 'Hello, World!'}


def do_something(fork_nr):
    pid = os.getpid()
    logging.info(f'in a thread, {pid=}')
    if fork_nr == 1:
        logging.info('we could start a WebSocket server...')
    else:
        logging.info('not the first worker, not starting any servers')


class HybridApplication(gunicorn.app.base.BaseApplication):
    forks = 0

    @classmethod
    def pre_fork(cls, server, worker):
        logging.info(f'about to fork a new worker #{cls.forks}')
        cls.forks += 1

    @classmethod
    def post_fork(cls, server, worker):
        thread = threading.Thread(
            target=do_something, args=(cls.forks,), daemon=True)
        thread.start()

    def __init__(self):
        self.options = {
            'bind': '127.0.0.1:8000',
            'pre_fork': self.pre_fork,
            'post_fork': self.post_fork,
            'workers': 4,
        }

        self.application = falcon.App()
        self.application.add_route('/hello', HelloWorld())

        super().__init__()

    def load_config(self):
        config = {key: value for key, value in self.options.items()
                  if key in self.cfg.settings and value is not None}
        for key, value in config.items():
            self.cfg.set(key.lower(), value)

    def load(self):
        return self.application


if __name__ == '__main__':
    HybridApplication().run()
```

This simplistic prototype is not infallible, as we should also handle server reloads, the worker getting killed, etc. Speaking of which, you should probably use another worker type than `sync` for potentially long running requests, or set a long timeout, because otherwise the worker can get killed, taking the WebSocket thread with it. Specifying a number of threads should automatically change your worker type into `gthread`.

Note that here I implemented a [custom Gunicorn application](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/custom.html), but you could achieve the same effect by specifying hooks via a configuration file.

Another option is to use the ASGI flavour of Falcon, and implement even the [WebSocket](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/websocket.html) part inside your app:

```py
import asyncio
import logging

import falcon.asgi

logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)


class HelloWorld:
    async def on_get(self, req, resp):
        resp.media = {'message': 'Hello, World!'}

    async def on_websocket(self, req, ws):
        await ws.accept()
        logging.info(f'WS accepted {req.path=}')

        try:
            while True:
                await ws.send_media({'message': 'hi'})
                await asyncio.sleep(10)
        finally:
            logging.info(f'WS disconnected {req.path=}')


app = falcon.asgi.App()
app.add_route('/hello', HelloWorld())
```

Note that Gunicorn itself does not "speak" ASGI, so you would either need to use an ASGI app server, or use Gunicorn as a process manager for [Uvicorn workers](https://www.uvicorn.org/deployment/#gunicorn).
For instance, assuming your file is called `test.py`, you could run Uvicorn directly as:

```
pip install uvicorn[standard]

uvicorn test:app
```

However, if you went the ASGI route, you would need to implement your responders as coroutine functions (`async def on_get(...)` etc), or run your synchronous DB code in a threadpool executor.